# Nginx load balance based on IP

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

We currently use an Nginx server for load balancing. We would like our office IP to be redirected to a specific server, where as all other traffic is load balanced normally.

Is this possible?

Comment: better ask at serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple redirect with any web server (Apache, Tomcat, nginx, etc).
For example, on Java you can create a simple index.jsp with the following:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Your Company</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.yourloadbalance.com/favicon.png">
</head>
<body>
<%
response.sendRedirect("www.yourloadbalance.com");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

This piece of code will redirect each request to the given URL, in your case to the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a working config but I hope the main idea is clear

```
map $remote_addr $backend {
    default app-servers;
    192.168.1.1 dev-servers; # office IP
}

upstream app-servers { # this is normal upstreams group
    server ...;
    server ...;
}

upstream dev-servers { # this is upstream(s) for Office IP
    server ...; 
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name bar.foo.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$backend;
    }
}
```